# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 17.04 or download any Ubuntu software

Tags: upgrade, mount, dpkg

`sudo apt-get upgrade` returns this:

```
dpkg: error processing package mount (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mount
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have seen this question asked before and have tried `sudo apt -- reinstall mount` which returns:
`E: Invalid operation reinstall` and I have tried various ways of reinstalling mount as advised but nothing works and I'm regretting installing 17.04 now.

Any help gratefully received. Mick

Comment: I believe that the form of the command should be `sudo apt install --reinstall mount`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for apt reinstall is incorrect. Try
`sudo apt install --reinstall mount`

Comment: I had the same suggestion as a comment, as I am unsure that this will actually fix the problem that the OP has.  There may be some additional difficulties, as `apt` does not retain the downloaded packages by default.

Comment: This has fixed the problem, very grateful to Michael Thomas and Charles Green.